# When I call Tolist it takes so long to convert, how can I improve this?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following bit of code and the last statement with the toList takes a long time.  Any ideas how I can improve this?

```
//This statement takes less than 1 second
    var inspectorData = context.COESDetails.Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth.Contains(criteria.AuditYear)).Select(x => x.Inspector).Where(y => y.Id != 0).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Firstname).ToList();

//This statement takes less than 1 second
var coesData = context.COESDetails.Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth.Contains(criteria.AuditYear)).ToList();

//this takes less than 1 second
var nonComplianceData = inspectorData
                .Select(ud =>
                    new NonComplianceData
                    {
                        InspectorId = ud.Id,
                        InspectorName = ud.Firstname + " " + ud.Surname,
                        FullYearData = Constants.Months.Select(month => new MonthData
                        {
                            Month  = month,
                            TotalAuditsCompleted = coesData.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected),
                            TotalNoDefects = coesData.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected && x.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any())
                        }).ToList()


                    });


// this statement takes about 14 seconds
return nonComplianceData.ToList();
```

I thought when I called the toList() in the first two statements, I thought the query was being executed and I had the required data.  So why is the last Tolist() taking so long? considering all the required data is there already..

any insights? thoughts?

Comment: The `Select` does nothing but creating a query, the `ToList` executes it and creates a collection from the result. The same with the `Where` above. You should read about [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: If it takes 14 seconds to run that query then you either need to change the query, or change how you're using the result. Why must you return the `List` instead of an `IEnumerable` (which would allow better lazy-evaluation)? You could also make `NonComplianceData.FullYearData` an `IEnumerable` (assuming it's readonly) which would do similar.

Comment: Is anything being lazy loaded? I notice the last linq statement building `nonComplianceData` accesses a lot of properties of entities returned from the context above.

Comment: is the `context` Entity Framework DbContext?

Comment: thanks guys, yeah it was to do with the two counts.. lazy loading.  I just assumed because I was doing ToList in the coesDetails, all the associated entities would be loaded eagerly.. I was wrong... thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework (or other ORM)...
Those `coesData.Count(...` cause loading `UploadCOESDetails`and `COESDetailsCOESDefects` lazily.

Use

```
context.COESDetails
    .Include(x => x.UploadCOESDetails)
    .Include(x => x.COESDetailsCOESDefects)
```

to load them eagerly.

Or pick the things you need in the query

```
var coesData = context.CoesData.Select(x => new 
{ 
    x.Id,
    x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId,
    x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth,
    x.InspectorId,
    x.AuditType,
    /* etc. */

    DefectCount = x.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Count(),
    /* or this if it works... */
    HasDefects = x.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  That brought the entire operation down to 2 seconds.  I completely forgot that UploadCOESDetails and COESDetailsCOESDefects were used via lazy loading.  Awesome work, much appreciated.  Just one thing though.. to load the entities eagerly, its .Include("UploadCOESDetails").Include("COESDetailsCOESDefects").. I knew what you meant.. thanks again... made such a diffrence

Answer (score 1):

When the last `ToList()` is called it will execute this code for all items in the `nonCompianceData` and that is probably what is taking so long.

```
FullYearData = Constants.Months.Select(month => new MonthData
{
    Month  = month,
    TotalAuditsCompleted = coesData.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected),
    TotalNoDefects = coesData.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected && x.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any())
}).ToList()
```

What I understand you should not use `ToList()` until really necessary, before that use the `IEnumerable<T>` query returned by Linq.

Other than that it is about optimizing your Linq to generate faster SQL.

Comment: `ToList` doesn't *cause* performance problems over deferred iteration. If you were to iterate normally it'd cost the same. `ToList` just costs up-front whereas with iteration you may or may not realise that cost. I suspect that the construction of the inner `FullYearData` property is actually what is costing, either due to nested iteration over large collections, or because of lazily loaded properties on entities. It really depends on if the entire enumerable is going to be accessed anyway. As with everything, it entirely depends.

Comment: I think if `ToList()` was not called for creating `coesData` it could lead to the properties used in the time costly query generating `nonComplianceData` would not be lazily loaded. Instead the whole query could executed in one SQL query.

Comment: Oh I see. Your answer eludes more to not calling `ToList` such that if people only do a partial iteration it doesn't cost as much.